# SQL - Get only data from 2 days ago

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to get data from n days ago to 2 days ago (ealiest data).

Here is my SQL request :

```
SELECT CDCATEGORY, DTLOGDATE
FROM ERRORS
```

How can i do that ?

Comment: What data type is the column `DTLOGDATE`?

Comment: I added oracle tag.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle you can substract days from a `date`.

So assuming that `DTLOGDATE` is a `date`, you can just do:

```
SELECT CDCATEGORY, DTLOGDATE FROM ERRORS WHERE DTLOGDATE > SYSDATE - 2
```

Or possibly, if you want the entire day:

```
SELECT CDCATEGORY, DTLOGDATE FROM ERRORS WHERE DTLOGDATE > TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 2
```

Comment: I have a problem, we are the 13 december. Your command give me all data from 12 and 13 december. What i want is all data before 11 december included. If i try to change ">" with "<" i have all data before 1 december included. Do you know why ?

Comment: @ClementRos: so do you want data from the December 11th at 00:00, is that correct?

Comment: I want data until December 11

Comment: @ClementRos: *until* or *from*?

Comment: Until please :)

Comment: This is different than the question that you originally asked... Anyway, `TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 2` gives you December 11 at 00:00. Then you can compare it with `DTLOGDATE`. If you want dates that are before December 11th at 00:00, then you can do `DTLOGDATE < TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 2`

Comment: It's strange because with your command i have only result before December 1. I do not understand why

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT CDCATEGORY, DTLOGDATE
FROM ERRORS where DTLOGDATE DTLOGDATE >= SYSDATE - n and DTLOGDATE <= SYSDATE - 2
```

Answer (score 0):

this code will give you last 2 day's data from database(DTLOGDATE) last date.

```
SELECT CDCATEGORY,  DTLOGDATE
FROM ERRORS
WHERE DTLOGDATE > (SELECT DATEADD(day, -2, MAX(DTLOGDATE) FROM ERRORS)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to make use of below code :

```
DECLARE @ERRORS TABLE (CDCATEGORY NVARCHAR(100),DTLOGDATE DATE)
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = GETUTCDATE() - 10, -- Your 'n' days
        @EndDate   DATE = GETUTCDATE() - 02

INSERT INTO @ERRORS
VALUES
('A','2019-12-01'),
('B','2019-12-05'),
('Z','2019-12-06'),
('R','2019-12-07'),
('Y','2019-12-10'),
('A','2019-12-11'),
('G','2019-12-12'),
('C','2019-12-13')

SELECT
    CDCATEGORY, 
    DTLOGDATE
FROM
    @ERRORS
WHERE 
    DTLOGDATE BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

Comment: Thank you but i do not know the @StartDate

Comment: If you create a stored procedure, you can pass the '@n_day' as a parameter. Your '@n_day' can be used in the stored procedure. Like : StartDate DATE = GETUTCDATE() - @n_day

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate the last time till when you want the data.

You want data before `12-dec-2019 00:00:00` which will include all the data **on or before** `11-dec-2019`.

Use following query:

```
SELECT CDCATEGORY, DTLOGDATE FROM ERRORS WHERE DTLOGDATE < TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 1;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Hi, it's strange because with your command i have only result before December 1. I do not understand why

Comment: It is actually not expected!!  What is the result of the `select trunc(sysdate) - 1 from dual` in your db?

Comment: 2019-12-12 00:00:00.0